# Why does overriding a function and doing nothing but calling the base-class implementation return different results than not overriding it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, overriding

This seems odd to me.  In a UITableViewController subclass, I have this...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: section)
}
```

To my knowledge, that *should* essentially be a no-op because it's simply passing through the value as if it weren't overridden.  However, the results are in fact different.

My guess is that the 'default' implementation doesn't actually call down to the base class, but rather checks for the optional delegate function, and if not defined (which it won't be if you don't override that), it does something else. However, I'm not sure that's correct as I'm specifically saying to override something, not just implementing a delegate method (which you don't have to override.)

So why would this return different results?

Comment: What does "the results are in fact different." mean?

Comment: When using the 'grouped' style, without the override, the headers appear as they normally would.  With it, the headers are clipped/missing.

Comment: On which OS/device are you experiencing this? Just tried in a simulator and I don't get different results. Perhaps you're doing some extra stuff besides the override?

Comment: Running in the sim.  Only other thing I'm doing is returning a value for the header text.  I'll take screenshots and will update the question.

Comment: When updating, can you also add details about the Xcode version and the simulator OS version?